# Why is it bad to commit lines with trailing whitespace into source control?

Tags: version-control

Why is it bad to check in lines with trailing whitespace to your source control?  What kinds of problems could that cause?

Comment: do you mean "check in" as in source control?

Comment: Yes - looks like somebody already edited the title to clarify. :)  I also added the edit to the body.  Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

False differences, basically. It's helpful if diffs only show "real" changes. Some diff programs will ignore whitespace, but it would be better just to avoid the dummy change in the first place.

Of course, it also doesn't help if it makes the line wrap on a colleague's machine.

Comment: Yeah! I hate that :) Delete the code if it's already in source control!

Comment: But... if your repo already HAS whitespace in it, and you, trying to be helpful, take it OUT, then YOU'RE the one creating a false difference.  ;)

Comment: Then do it once, only for that.  You won't have to live with the issue anymore and the changes are only whitespace, which can be seen as no change in several diff viewers that can be set to ignore whitespace.  Of course try to do this at the beginning of a dev cycle, not just before the project is about to end.

Answer (score 5):

Some editors automatically remove trailing whitespace, some don't. This creates diff noise and can cause merge conflicts.

Comment: You should coordinate with the people you're working with (colleagues, open-source crowd) what strategy everybody is using and make sure you all use the same strategy.

Answer (score 4):

It's like painting your walls, but not finishing the edges off properly, and going right onto the skirting board.

Comment: And then someone says you cant move into your house because you've got paint on your baseboards.

Answer (score 3):

Because many people remove them you will have them show up as modified lines in diff tools if you don't use all the options (say a plain old cvs diff) which means people see your line for no good reason.

In theory you could also have strings that wrap lines where whitespace would truly be bad, but... probably not your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I sort of agree with the other posts, but I would add that it's not bad *per se*. It is not a great practice, but that's the sort of thing that happens and you just sort of sigh and get on with things.

Comment: Bad practice is bad practice. It's not the most important thing, but if it can be easily fixed before committing then why not?

Answer (score 1):

Modern diff utilities don't get hung up on whitespace.