# Git shows warning for extra space at end of line in readme file

Tags: git, readme

I'm writing a `README.md`. I've added an extra space at the end of some lines. When I do `git diff` shows this as highlighted as below

[image: Git warning on extra space after a line]

Why the trailing whitespace is considered an error?

Comment: As mentioned in the last line. Are these errors or warnings? What is the reason for highlighting them?

Comment: These are not the difference between working tree and HEAD. These are all new lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it bad to commit lines with trailing whitespace into source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300489/why-is-it-bad-to-commit-lines-with-trailing-whitespace-into-source-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git will show you "common whitespace problems" such as trailing whitespace. You can control this behavior with the `core.whitespace` configuration option. `-trailing-space` will turn this highlighting off.

```
[core]
        whitespace = -trailing-space
```

I've never understood why this is considered a problem, but many people do, so I recommend stripping them off. You can configure your editor to strip trailing whitespace for you. If doing this for all documents doesn't appeal to you, use [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) to provide universal editor configurations for your projects.

```
root = true

[*]
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```

See also

- [Git Configuration](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) Pro Git.
- [git-config](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config) documentation

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Schwern. Is trailing whitespace a problem? In what use cases it could cause issues?

Comment: @GaneshSatpute: trailing whitespace annoys your co-workers. Unless of course it doesn't. (In other words, it's a personal preference thing.)

Comment: @GaneshSatpute I've been using Git for over 10 years and I've never heard a good explanation for why trailing whitespace is a problem. But so many people seem to think it's a problem (possibly because of Git highlighting it) that I strip it out to avoid time consuming style arguments. [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) makes it easy.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Schwern. I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

One reason I can think of is the line ending styles for git.

The question [git diff - show me line ending changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920650/git-diff-show-me-line-ending-changes) asked can be of some help as well.

Comment: Sorry, if I missed something but that answer talks about Linux vs Windows line endings. In my case, the error is about the extra space at the end of the line.

Comment: This might happen in case code is earlier checked in with different line endings and you have a different line ending styles, then you might face the problem. eg. if the same code is committed on Linux machine with Linux end styles and you are using windows machine with windows style line ending then this issue is faced.
However, I think @Schwern has a better explanation than mine.

Comment: I'm telling you it's not about Linux or Windows file endings